# `git add` adds ^M to the end of every line

Tags: git, vim, special-characters, newline, addition

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04. I'm editing files with **Vim**. Suddenly I started to notice that the changes that I make which I see with `git diff filename` contain `^M` at the end of every line that I've inserted or changed. So after I run `git add` to the `filename` I see with `git diff --staged` that **every line has** `^M` **at the end** and thus it's like if I made a **change to the whole file** even if I **changed only one line**. Please help me to understand what's going on here.

Comment: you have a misconfigured line ending handling. There are a lot of topics on the site about this - `core.safecrlf` and `core.autocrlf` are the settings you should fix. Note that after fixing you might need to recreate your local checkout.

Comment: Also, check out [this](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/).

Comment: @eis thanks for suggestion, but Blake's answer actually worked

Comment: yes, that's one way of resolving it as well. There are others, too, such as using .gitattributes for this. Each have their own characteristics and drawbacks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are your files being checked in from a Windows computer at any point? Windows adds `CR+LF` to line endings, while other OS's use `LF` only. If you've set `core.autocrlf` to `false` then `git diff` will highlight CR characters as `^M`. To turn this off, you can alter the `core.whitespace` setting:

```
git config --global core.whitespace cr-at-eol
```

Comment: It was edited probably on Windows before! It's routes.rb. Does that configuration completely ignores ^M or it actually doesn't insert them when staging, i.e. git-adding?

Comment: It causes ^M just not to be displayed but it exists in files anyway.

Comment: @Abdollah gets +1 there.  The ^M are still there. For me, this fix is worse than the disease.  I have ^M causing merge conflicts, but they are now invisible to me.  Blech.

Comment: Obrigado! Resolveu pra mim.

Answer (score 10):

This solved this problem for me, I quote from following source: [core.autocrlf explained](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2318)

Hope this helps someone!

**core.autocrlf**

If you’re programming on Windows and working with people who are not (or vice-versa), you’ll probably run into line-ending issues at some point. This is because Windows uses both a carriage-return character and a linefeed character for newlines in its files, whereas Mac and Linux systems use only the linefeed character. This is a subtle but incredibly annoying fact of cross-platform work; many editors on Windows silently replace existing LF-style line endings with CRLF, or insert both line-ending characters when the user hits the enter key.

Git can handle this by auto-converting CRLF line endings into LF when you add a file to the index, and vice versa when it checks out code onto your filesystem. You can turn on this functionality with the core.autocrlf setting. If you’re on a Windows machine, set it to true – this converts LF endings into CRLF when you check out code:

```
$ git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

Comment: This solved the issue for me since I code on windows but deploy on linux. 
I prefer not changing the content rather than ignoring updates because the changes are expected.

Answer (score 6):

I faced a similar problem when I copied my whole project directly from Windows to Linux. Regarding this [document](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/using-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings), I ran the following command on my Linux Terminal and the problem was resolved:

```
$ git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

Comment: Also, to change the line-endings you may use `git add --renormalize .`